# Which Design Pattern is used in Android Glide Library?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, design-patterns, open-source

The Android Glide library can be used in the following way :

```kotlin
 Glide.with(context).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner).into(myImageView);
```

I have the following doubts :

1. Which Design Pattern is being used here ? Is it Builder Pattern alone or Chain of Responsibility Pattern or is it any new Design Pattern ?
2. In which scenarios should such a Pattern be used ?
3. Can you share any reference link for learning about this Pattern or maybe a Kotlin/Java Example for the same ?

I have tried exploring [Glide's Source Code on GitHub](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), but I couldn't deduce the Design Pattern used and couldn't understand the Implementation.

Comment: Why do you think that every piece of code/API should follow some named design pattern? There are a few specific problems where someone invented a non-obvious way of solving them, and named that solution style a "design pattern". They are useful **if you have that specific problem**, but not at all a universal thing.

Comment: I do know that every piece of code/API need not necessarily follow some named design pattern. I saw such usage of "Class.with(context).doSomething()" in few other Android libraries too. The naming conventions of the methods of such libraries seem to be similar. But, I couldn't understand how the methods were designed. Couldn't find an answer on the Internet. Hence, I posted on StackOverFlow.

Comment: Maybe you're just looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface ?

Comment: This is the First Time I am hearing about Fluent Interface. But, it seems to match the implementation of Glide methods. Seems like they have used a combo of Fluent Interface and Builders. Thanks a lot for sharing this.